# Erasing lines in specific region in a plot (matplotlib, python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am working on plotting the following figure (https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7LvO.png). I do not want the lines to show after intersecting with the red line (so in the black region there should be no blue and orange).

I tried to plot only the relevant parts of the line in the case they intersect with the red line. But it seems that once i plot other lines that *are* in the domain x = [-1,1] all the lines will be plotted on this domain. Which is why there is still blue and orange after the intersection. Does anybody now a clever way to make sure the lines do not show in this region?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure the exact task. However, per your questions, once you erase the line, it appears you may end up with rectangles. So if you know the coordinates for the exacts points of intersection  I suggest you use patches to draw them directly as rectangles. The library can be further explored here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html

Answer (score 1):

You can manually specify `zorder` of the black region (which I believe is generated using `fill_between` or something similar) to be higher than that of the curves. See [demo from the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html).

Answer (score 1):

By default, surfaces are drawn behind lines. This is controlled by the [zorder attribute](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html). Here's an example of how to use this:

In this example program I wrote the default z-order is used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y_1 = 1-x
y_2 = np.exp(x)

plt.plot(x, y_1, c="b")
plt.plot(x, y_2, c="r")
plt.fill_between(x, np.zeros(len(x)), y_2, color="black")

plt.show()
```

By default lines have z-order 2, and a surface has z-order 1. This means the surface is drawn behind the lines. The second line is drawn over the first since it is plotted later.

To change this you can manually change the `zorder` attribute as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y_1 = 1-x
y_2 = np.exp(x)

plt.plot(x, y_1, c="b")
plt.plot(x, y_2, c="r", zorder=2.2)
plt.fill_between(x, np.zeros(len(x)), y_2, color="black", zorder=2.1)

plt.show()
```

Now the surface has `zorder` equal to 2.1, meaning it will be drawn over all lines with default Z-order. I made sure the second line has a higher Z-order to make sure the border of the surface is still on top.

I advise looking at the [Z-order documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) when choosing what Z-order to use, to avoid unexpected behaviour like lines being drawn on top of the legend, which is why I used values of z-order between 2 and 3.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, this is exactly the answer I was hoping I could find.